# draw XAML image using GDI

Tags: xaml, rendering, gdi

I have a GDI rendering system. And I would like enhance its capabilities by including XAML.

I am looking for a tool which would parse a XAML described image and draw the image using GDI. As the GDI does not support advanced features like Alpha blending, anti-aliasing, linear gradient etc, I just need the tool to draw the basic objects like rectangle, circles etc.

Is there any tool/api in C/C++ that could help me.